# How to create a network profile in Azure Fluent?

Tags: .net, azure, azure-container-service, azure-container-instances

The REST client here [createorupdate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/virtualnetwork/networkprofiles/createorupdate) shows how to create a network profile, but there doesn't seem to be any corresponding code in Azure Fluent. When creating a Container Instance in [Azure CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-instances/container-instances-vnet), it automatically creates a Network Profile, but the Fluent class for [Network Profiles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.management.containerservice.fluent.models.networkprofile?view=azure-dotnet) doesn't seem to do anything.
So how can you create a network profile in Fluent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you find in [Network Profiles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.management.containerservice.fluent.models.networkprofile?view=azure-dotnet) is a model for container service, not an available interface for the network. What you need is the interface [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.management.network.fluent.inetworkprofilesoperations.createorupdatewithhttpmessagesasync?view=azure-dotnet#Microsoft_Azure_Management_Network_Fluent_INetworkProfilesOperations_CreateOrUpdateWithHttpMessagesAsync_System_String_System_String_Microsoft_Azure_Management_Network_Fluent_Models_NetworkProfileInner_System_Collections_Generic_Dictionary_System_String_System_Collections_Generic_List_System_String___System_Threading_CancellationToken_):

> CreateOrUpdateWithHttpMessagesAsync(String, String,
> NetworkProfileInner, Dictionary<String,List>,
> CancellationToken)

This is the right one for Network.